# ReferenceError: axios is not defined

Tags: javascript, express, axios, pug

[screenshot of browser developer tool - network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5EPy.png)

I have included the script to my base.pug file

script(scr='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js')

When I load the page and check the browser developer tool > network, all the other bootstrap files, jquery files etc were loaded but axios.min.js didn't load.

When I execute the login.js as shown in the code below, I get 'Axios not defined' error in the console.

Hope someone can give me some hint and guidance.

I have tried putting the script at the top of the base.pug page, I have checked for any syntax error etc. I have tried using alternative link https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js - keep getting the same error.

base.pug file

```
    body
        // HEADER
        include _header

        // CONTENT
        block content



        // FOOTER
        include _footer

        // FOOTER
        include _footer

script(src='/js/login.js') 
script(scr='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js')

script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js' integrity='sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1' crossorigin='anonymous')
```

login.js file

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
    head
        block head     
            meta(charset='UTF-8')
            meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
            meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='ie=edge')
            link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf' crossorigin='anonymous')
            link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T' crossorigin='anonymous')
            link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css')
            link(rel='icon' type='image/ico' href='/img/favicon.ico')

            title Sales App #{title}

    body
        // HEADER
        include _header

        // CONTENT
        block content



        // FOOTER
        include _footer

    script(src='/js/login.js') 
    script(scr='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js')

    script(
    src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js'
    integrity='sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg='
    crossorigin='anonymous')
    script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js' integrity='sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1' crossorigin='anonymous')
```

ReferenceError: axios is not defined
    at login (login.js:7)
    at HTMLFormElement. (login.js:26)

Comment: Move `login.js` after `axios.js`

Answer (score 0):

move your scripts after all the cdns becuase your script will be loaded before them making them undefined at the time of the script being loaded.

base.pug

```
    body
        // HEADER
        include _header

        // CONTENT
        block content



        // FOOTER
        include _footer

        // FOOTER
        include _footer

script(scr='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js')
script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js' integrity='sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1' crossorigin='anonymous')
script(src='/js/login.js')
```

login.js

```js
doctype html
html(lang='en')
    head
        block head     
            meta(charset='UTF-8')
            meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
            meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='ie=edge')
            link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf' crossorigin='anonymous')
            link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T' crossorigin='anonymous')
            link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css')
            link(rel='icon' type='image/ico' href='/img/favicon.ico')

            title Sales App #{title}

    body
        // HEADER
        include _header

        // CONTENT
        block content



        // FOOTER
        include _footer


    script(scr='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js')

    script(
    src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js'
    integrity='sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg='
    crossorigin='anonymous')
    script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js' integrity='sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1' crossorigin='anonymous')
    script(src='/js/login.js')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried moving the scripts(src='/js/login.js) to the bottom  - still the same error. I have also tried removing all the bootstrap and jquery scripts. Just loading only axios and login.js - also get the same error. Tried clearing caches on browser, restart server - still getting the same error.

Comment: I tried the scripts on another project folder - it is able to load. I think I will just migrate the codes to a new project folder to see if it resolve the issue.

Comment: are you importing axios in the file you are trying to use it?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to resolve this. It was due to some extra spacing at scripts for loading bootstraps. Not sure if this is the cause because I had tried removing all scripts for downloading bootstrap it didn't work..now it suddenly works. Anyway, case closed.

Answer (score 0):

Back then in time you had an error due to a typo during your axios package loading, it's `src` should be, not `scr`

your sample

```
script(scr='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js')
```

should be

```
script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js')
```

I realize a long time passed, but for future readers should be useful.